# Maximum number of supervisord managed processes?

Tags: supervisord

We have an issue with supervisord being unable to handle more than 200 processes at once - adding any more causes it to die on startup.

Anyone have any experience with supervisord and a large number of managed processes?

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out - it's a bug in supervisord that doesn't allow for more than 1024 file descriptors.

https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/26

Comment: If not you should try running as Root because that limitation is not from supervisord but from the system

Comment: There's a patch listed on the page I included that fixes the issue.  It isn't system related.